# ex17.rb:5:in `open': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError) from ex17.rb:5:in `<main>'

Tags: ruby, implicit-conversion

I am going through "Ruby the Hard Way".  Typing in the exercises as instructed.  Got to Exercise 17 and as far as i can tell typed in correctly but when i run it get this error:
ex17.rb:5:in `open': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError) from ex17.rb:5:in` '
Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

put the 5 in the code below to show line 5. I think the error means it is in line 5.

This is the exercise:

from_file, to_file = ARGV

puts "Copying from #{from_file} to #{to_file}"

5 in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read

puts "The input file is #{indata.length} bytes long"

puts "Does the output file exist? #{Fileexist?(to_file)}"
puts "Ready , hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
$stdin.gets

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

puts "Alright, all done."

out_file.close
in_file.close

Answer (score 0):

I was running this on the Terminal, I ran it as >ruby ex17.rb, without submitting a filename afterwards. So, on the prompt, I should have submitted it as >ruby ex17.rb with a file name.